# Building module in Android Open Source Project

Tags: java, android, input, build, android-source

I've made some edits to the code of the Android keyboard (here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/). I'm left with the folders and files: Android.mk, CleanSpec.mk, common/, dictionaries/, java-overridable/, java/,
   native/, tests/, tools/.

How can I now build this as an APK I can put onto a device? I've read Google's build instructions (https://source.android.com/source/requirements.html) but I'm really unsure how to do this still. Could someone provide an idiot's guide to it, for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the path of the Android.mk file, run `mm`. Checking the output and you will find the apk is in somewhere in out/target/product/...

Comment: I get "-bash: mm: command not found". How exactly do you run the 'mm' command? Thank you.

Comment: Did you use `. build/envsetup.sh`?